# How can I speed up Visual Studio builds to match MSBuild parallel performance?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, msbuild

I encounter a noticable difference in the speed when building the same solution one time with Devenv and the other time with msbuild /m.

As an information I have set the parameter "number of parallel build processes" in Visual studio to 4.

Is there any posiblity to speed up the build inside Visual Studio (Version 9.0.30729.1 SP)?

Comment: I had to remove the images from your post because ImageShack has deleted them and replaced them with advertising. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263771/215468 for more information. If possible, it would be great for you to re-upload them. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, at I have not stored the images on my pc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This won't answer your exact question, but take a look at [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HackParallelMSBuildsFromWithinTheVisualStudioIDE.aspx) post by Scott Hanselman. Basically, the problem is that VS does not officially support parallel builds for managed languages, so you'll have to "hack" a bit in order to get parallel builds.

Comment: Thank you. It worked! Hopefully the guys from MS will not only preach paralellism but do something with it in their own tools in the future.